# Руководство по C++ для считывания данных из ttys0

Tags: c++, linux, c, com-порт

Посоветуйте туториал. Желательно готовый класс, чтобы можно было установить соединение,
допустим, 9600, data bits 8, stop bits 1. А принимаемые данные, например, выводить в консоль (программирование под linux, считывание данных с com порта).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Руководства:

- [Serial Programming/Serial Linux](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming:Serial_Linux)
- [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](https://web.archive.org/web/20140820103552/http://linuxland.itam.nsc.ru/misc/other19/index.html)

Библиотеки:

- [Serial Port Programming in C++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libserial/)